# How to filter a dataframe with values of another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I want to filter the first with condition ">" and/or "<" present in another ones.
Condition should be:

```
if df1.Type=df2.Parameters:
   dfFinal= df1.Amount > df2.Amount & df1.Count < df2.Count
```

for each row.
The result will be the dfTotal, all dataframes of df1 that have the ctwo conditions satisfied.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car', 'bike','car', 'motorbike','bike','bike'], 'Amount': [40,3,50, 699,60,90], 'Count': [10,1,2,4,3,2],'Item': ['a','b','t','u','i','e']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Parameters': ['Amount', 'Count'], 'car': [30, 3], 'bike': [40,4], 'motorbike': [1000,7]})
```

The final dataframe with only the row of df1 that satisfied the conditions made by value target of df2:

```
dfTotal = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car','bike','bike'], 'Amount': [50,60,90], 'Count': [2,3,2], 'Item': ['t','i','e']})
```

I have already open a question, but with different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could go about this problem is by merging your DataFrames into one, and then running a query on the result for your target rows.

Assuming your data is given as described, first we need to modify df2 to be able to be merged with df1 by transposing and formatting the columns.

```
df2_modified = df2.T 
new_header = df2_modified.iloc[0] # Get the new header names
df2_modified = df2_modified[1:] # Remove header row
df2_modified.columns = new_header 
df2_modified = df2_modified.reset_index(names=['Type'])

# Rename the columns so we know what we're comparing
name_mapper = {'Amount' : 'amount_compare', 'Count' : 'count_compare'}
df2_modified = df2_modified.rename(name_mapper, axis = 1)
df2_modified
```

This should give us:

|  | Type | amount_compare | count_compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | car | 30 | 3 |
| 1 | bike | 40 | 4 |
| 2 | motorbike | 1000 | 7 |

Then we can [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two on the *Type* column with:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2_modified, on='Type')
```

It will repeat our comparison values for each type.

|  | Type | Amount | Count | Item | amount_compare | count_compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | car | 40 | 10 | a | 30 | 3 |
| 1 | car | 50 | 2 | t | 30 | 3 |
| 2 | bike | 3 | 1 | b | 40 | 4 |
| 3 | bike | 60 | 3 | i | 40 | 4 |
| 4 | bike | 90 | 2 | e | 40 | 4 |
| 5 | motorbike | 699 | 4 | u | 1000 | 7 |

Now we can filter the data with [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
dfTotal = df_merged.query('Amount > amount_compare & Count < count_compare')
```

Which will (mostly) give our desired result:

|  | Type | Amount | Count | Item | amount_compare | count_compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 50 | 2 | t | 30 | 3 |
| 3 | bike | 60 | 3 | i | 40 | 4 |
| 4 | bike | 90 | 2 | e | 40 | 4 |

The only extra step that's optionally needed to get to your example `dfTotal` DataFrame would be to remove the comparison columns. This can be done easily with [drop().](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
dfTotal.drop(['amount_compare', 'count_compare'], axis = 1)
```

|  | Type | Amount | Count | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 50 | 2 | t |
| 3 | bike | 60 | 3 | i |
| 4 | bike | 90 | 2 | e |

Comment: Thanks! i didn't think a solution with the merge.